# How should we update our .gitignore when using Sitecore Rocks?

Tags: sitecore-rocks, git

With the switch to Sitecore 8 we've recently begun using Sitecore Rocks for development.

Sitecore Rocks adds at least the following files to the site (we're a little backwards still in that our working project directory is currently built on top of the core Sitecore files, but we do at least web publish to a different directory):

- Website/sitecore/shell/WebService/Browse.aspx
- Website/sitecore/shell/WebService/Service2.asmx
- Website/sitecore/shell/WebService/Sitecore.Rocks.Validation.ashx

And the following to the project directory:

- *.csproj.sitecore

Since a username is added to the ***.csproj.sitecore** file I assume that should be excluded, but are there any other Sitecore Rocks-related files that should be excluded from source control?

Comment: You should really work outside the core Sitecore files, and move to using the [Sitecore Nuget feed](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/sitecore_public_nuget_packages_faq), it would solve these kinds of problems and should not take long to do.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the official NuGet feed; last I heard they were still recommending using local NuGet. It's on the schedule to do that, but at this point we can't really devote much time to technical debt like that. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [GitHub repository for Sitecore.Rocks](https://github.com/JakobChristensen/Sitecore.Rocks/tree/master/src/Sitecore.Rocks.Server), the only files installed into Sitecore by the Sitecore.Rocks extension are these:

> - Browse.aspx
> - Service2.asmx
> - *Service2.asmx.cs* (codefile, not deployed)
> - Sitecore.Rocks.Validation.ashx
> - *Sitecore.Rocks.Validation.ashx.cs* (codefile, not deployed)

Reference: https://github.com/JakobChristensen/Sitecore.Rocks/tree/master/src/Sitecore.Rocks.Server/sitecore/shell/WebService

And since the .cs files would be compiled into the DLL itself, that confirms your original assumption about what you need to exclude from source control.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you add files related to a VS plugin to source control? I would say it is safe to ignore all the files related to Sitecore Rocks. Each developer creates his/her own connection in Sitecore Rocks Explorer which will install the necessary files in their Sitecore instance. This is similar to the service installed by TDS which is also ignored for source control.

Comment: Yup, that's why I'm asking what files should be excluded from source control. The ***.csproj.sitecore** file is an easy one, exactly because it includes the user name.

Comment: You should see all unversioned files when you would like to commit. And then you can ignore these one by one.

Comment: As TRNKTMS said, ignore all unversioned filed should work. I cracked open the plugin and it seems like it's just the WebService folder that you need to ignore.